# Dell keeps booting to old SSD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd, bios

My Dell G5 5590 has a 250GB SSD and a 1TB HDD. I bought a Samsung Evo 870 1TB SSD, and used Samsung's Data Migration tool to clone from the 250GB to the Evo.

Then, I opened the laptop and installed the SSD. I was expecting to see two 2.5" drives, and replace the 250GB with the Evo, but the 250GB drive is a weird little Hynix chip thing, under the silver panel just above the HDD case in the image below. So instead I replaced the HDD with the Evo.

But now I can't get the laptop to boot from the Evo. I've tried in BIOS to set the sequence to start with the Evo, it still boots from the old one. I disabled the Windows Boot Manager and the old drive from Bios boot sequence completely, but it still boots from the old one. I don't know how to stop it booting from the old drive!? Using `bcdedit` seems a bit scary if I get anything wrong. Is there a way to get the Evo to be the boot disk, so I can wipe the Hynix?

[image]

Comment: So you end up having both a clone and the source of the clone in the same machine. You probably want to remove the 250GB M.2 SSD, then see if everything works well with the 1TB SATA drive. If so, install the 250GB back (and remove the 1TB) and wipe it with/from e.g. a Linux live USB (`blkdiscard`, assuming it's at least a partially RZAT drive; or `wipefs` the partitions and the drive), then install the 1TB back again. (Instead of all the removing/installing manipulation, you may also check whether your UEFI settings allow you to disable SATA port / M.2 slot.)

Comment: If you have you cloned the total disk, including the EFI partition, then the boot will be from the first EFI partition found across all the internal disks. Evidently, the SSD precedes the HDD in the search order of the BIOS, so the SSD is always found first. Do you have a way of physically disconnecting the SSD, to test if the HDD can boot?